# $x_n=\frac{n^2}{n^2+c}\left(an+b\right)\rightarrow c=0$ ? where$x_n$ is a general term of a arithmetic series.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

If  $$\frac{n^2}{n^2+c}\left(an+b\right)$$ is a general term of a arithmetic series, can we deduce that $c=0$? where $a,b,c\in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: trivial case: if $a=b=0$, then $c$ can be any real

Comment: if trivial case is excluded, then yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{n^2}{n^2+c}(an+b) = pn+q$$

$$\implies n^2(an+b) = (n^2+c)(pn+q)$$

$$\implies (a-p)n^3 + (b-q)n^2 -cpn - cq = 0$$

For the above equation to be true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $a = p$, $b = q$ and $c = 0$ unless $a=b=p=q=0$ in which case $c$ can take any value.

Note that I used the following result,

If a cubic polynomial $g$ with real coefficients has more than $3$ roots for $g(x)=0$ then the polynomial should be identically equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: The difference of two arithmetic progressions is an arithmetic progression.

Proof: Let $x_n=an+b,y_n=cn+d$. Then $z_n=x_n-y_n=(a-c)n+(b-d).$

If we detone: $y_n=an+b$, then:
$$x_n=\frac{n^2}{n^2+c}y_n \Rightarrow y_n-x_n=\frac{cx_n}{n^2}=z_n$$ if and only if $c=0$.